Adjective for someone that refuses help from others?
I have spent an embarrassing amount of time searching for an answer to this question with no results. I am looking for an adjective that describes someone that refuses to accept help from others.
I don't think that the word independent or altruistic would be suitable for this.
While this question was close to what I was looking for, it is an adjective that describes someone that refuses help for the sake of helping others. I am curious if there is an adjective that specifically denotes someone that does not accept the assistance of others without the connotation of selflessness.

There is a similar question on English Language and Usage from 2019, which was closed for not providing enough detail for a single-word-request, but has some answers.

Lone wolf comes to mind. Similar to independent, but with the added connotation that the person not only can do things for themself, but strongly prefers to. It implies other things too though, like overall self-isolation, not just refusing help. It's also a noun.
